# Problem with downloading files to SD card

Tags: sd-card, chrome-for-android

I have a problem with downloading to my SD card and I tried using different browsers: chrome, brave, firefox but couldn't find a satisfactory solution. Basically on Chrome I set the download location to SD card and the path is "sdcard/../../Android/data/org.android.chrome/Downloads'. This is the only choice under SD card so I select that. But when I download any file, chrome displays "download error" in the notification bar, but the file has been downloaded to the above path. The only way to open the file is to use a file manager and navigate to that directory which is a hassle if I have to do that each time.
​

I tried the same with firefox beta and about:config settings following instructions floating around on google. But Firefox completely ignores the folder path and always downloads to the internal storage.

​

I don't mind saving to that weird path but the download manager I have (Files by Google) does not recognize it as a downloads folder and so the file does not show up in my Downloaded files list, so it's kind of annoying.

​I have a MIUI 12.0.4 phone running on Android 10.

Does anyone else have experience with this sort of bug and if so is there a solution for that? (Alternative brower, other settings, a way to map that folder to Downloads in file manager, anything is welcome)

Comment: Just to avoid a misunderstanding: the path `/sdcard` and all directories below this path also are located in the internal storage. The path is just called sd-card for historical reasons.

Comment: @Robert the path is copied directly from the file manager and I can see the file downloaded to that location, it's just not convenient to access

Comment: Can you check Chrome's app permission for the storage permission? [Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes) changed their storage access policy.

Comment: Thanks. I have added storage permission for chrome but there's nothing specific to SD card in there

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue on my Vivo v21e. But I found the solution. You can use 1DM downloader (available on play store) as an external download manager but you have to use Firefox to make it work. Just go to the Firefox settings and turn on external download manager after downloading 1DM and it'll fix the problem..